# Paypal - post product to shopping cart from Java Servlet - how to?

Tags: java, forms, servlets, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a product page on my website and for each item there is an encrypted Paypal Add to Cart button. An example of the `<form>` from Paypal is below :

```
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7----------END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I want to add the `onSubmit` handler to the form so when a customer clicks the add to cart button they will be shown a form/questionnaire on the product page that they must fill out and submit **before** the item is added to the cart.

Upon a successful submission of the form, of which is processed by my Java Servlet, can I put some sort of code in the Servlet to add the item to the cart? A direct post to Paypal? Otherwise, the only way I see getting the item into the cart is by requesting that the customer click on the Add to Cart button again.

**The flow of my concept would like this -**

Product page >

Add to Cart button clicked (onSubmit handler in paypal form code) >

div with my form, not paypal, has fields for user to fill out, this form isshown on the page >

user fills in my form and submits >

servlet processes form field information >

form successfully filled out and processed >

at this point I need to add the item to the cart and send the user back to the Products page.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are sending user email id  with custom attribute ..

up on successfull submission .In do post of your servlet

String emailId = req.getParameter("custom");

here the magic code you want

```
    if (emailId != null && transactionID != null) {
            if (!(paymentStatus.equals("Completed")
                    || paymentStatus.equals("Processed") || paymentStatus
                        .equals("Pending"))) {
                log.info("Paypal not completed.");
                sendInfo("Your process is not completed", req, resp);
            } else {
                if (transactionType.equals("subscr_cancel")) {
                    removeClientSubscription(emailId);  //This will hit my DB to update user
                } else {
                    log.info("Payment completed with Status - "
                            + paymentStatus);
                    upgradeClient(params, emailId);//this line hit my DB to update user
                }
            }
```

Comment: if any doubts let me know ..i dealt with a complete cycle of paypal .

Comment: Thank you for the reply:) I'm not sure if we're on the same page though, I want to post the item to the paypal shopping cart IF the form the customer filled out was successful, then the servlet will return the user to the Products page of my Store and the item will be in the cart.

Comment: so before submission you want to track the paypal button click ??

Comment: I've added the flow of what I'm trying to accomplish to the end of my original post:)

Comment: And when you are going to submit paypal then ?as per you flow it never goes to paypal..

Comment: Posting the item to the shopping cart (paypal) occurs right before I send the user back to my product page. I see what you mean though, after the item is put in the cart, the customer needs to see the cart on paypal's end since they might be done shopping and want to checkout. So then, is it still possible to implement this concept? Or do I need a different strategy?

Comment: you are asking that ..you want to show cart items on paypals website ?

Comment: I think this is getting more confusing then it needs to be. I just want to be able to manually post an item to my paypal shopping cart, doing so within my servlet code 'after' I execute some code prior to this action within the same servlet. Is this possible?

Comment: So ..now i got the ..So on PayPal form submit handler make an Ajax request and on success of the Ajax submit the form ..if you enter into servlet it will create mess inside due to some restrictions over papal and it will turns like an web service instead of form submission ..  cheers :)..